# Docker containers using AWS cloudformation

Tags: docker, aws-cloudformation

I tried the instructions mentioned here...

https://github.com/tleyden/open-ocr/wiki/Installation-on-CoreOS-Fleet

This will initiate OCR API using tessaract package. But I am not able to start the services.

```
core@ip-172-31-17-221 ~ $ fleetctl list-units
UNIT                            MACHINE                         ACTIVE          SUB
httpd.service                   8f3aebfb.../172.31.48.14        failed          failed
rabbitmq.service                4e104b63.../172.31.17.221       failed          failed
rabbitmq_announce.service       4e104b63.../172.31.17.221       inactive        dead
worker.1.service                8f3aebfb.../172.31.48.14        failed          failed
worker.2.service                4e104b63.../172.31.17.221       failed          failed
worker.3.service                6cedf4ff.../172.31.12.203       failed          failed
```

Where do I get cloudformation logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once everything is provisioned, the CloudFormation part is done and the CloudFormation logs will only tell you about provisioning information. So the issue here is with the actual software and not with CloudFormation.

That being said, I happen to be quite experienced with Fleet and to get the logs for these services there's a couple things you can do.

First, try to query the logs using:

`fleetctl journal httpd.service`, `fleetctl journal worker.1.service`, etc.

If that doesn't work, try to SSH into one host and use:
`journalctl -u httpd.service`

As final note, I don't know if you want to run this inside a production environment but I think you should know that **fleetd** is being deprecated.

> fleet is no longer developed or maintained by CoreOS. After February
>   1, 2018, a fleet container image will continue to be available from
>   the CoreOS Quay registry, but will not be shipped as part of Container
>   Linux. CoreOS instead recommends Kubernetes for all clustering needs.

If I were you, I'd look for a similar solution running on either Kubernetes or AWS ECS.